# Sum() before Changes() in PromQL

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql, grafana-alerts

So I was trying to measure the latest time a counter had increased in its value.
Let's call the counter "my_service_counter", it has multiple labels couple of them are "pod" and "id".
This counter is increased every time a new job is launched in one of the pods.
I was trying to aggregate based on "id", meaning I wanted the total sum for each id. The job with same Id can be the deployed on different pods.

I tried to run this query,

`time() - max_over_time(timestamp(changes(my_service_counter{status="success"}[5m]) > 0)[24h:1m])` 
this ran fine but this does not aggregate based on id, so I added

`time() - max_over_time(timestamp(changes(add (my_service_counter{status="success"}) by (id) [5m]) > 0)[24h:1m])`

The problem is
`changes()` 
require a range vector, while the `add()` returns a instant vector, so the query does not run.

Is there any way around it? should I change my whole approach?

Comment: 1. I hope by `add` you meant `sum` as in title, because otherwise I don't know what we are talking about.

Comment: 2. You can use [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax. Basically, change `[5m]` to `[5m:]`

Comment: Additionally, usually `sum` should be applied after `changes`.

Comment: yeah I meant sum(), that was a typo on my part